# cannot call the function in child from the parent

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a game using C++ in Qt creator.

I can call the fuctions of the child class in main without an issue, but when I try to call a function in child class from my parent class, the program unexpectedly closes.

I have declared all the public attributes in the .h file of the parent class. T tried removing those attributes and placing them inside the .h file of the child class, then it works fine. But W want to keep them in the parent class and access those from the child class.

Please help get this to work, I tried several times but I could not figure it out.

**.h file of parent class:**

```
class Game:public QGraphicsView,public home{

Q_OBJECT

public:

Game(QWidget* parent=0);

virtual ~Game(){}

void createBlockCol(double x);
void creatBlockGrid();
virtual void setbackground();

QPushButton *btn2;
QPushButton *btn3;
QPushButton *btn4;
QGraphicsScene* scene;
QGraphicsScene *scene2;
QGraphicsView* view;
QPushButton *btn;
QPushButton *btn1;
QGraphicsProxyWidget *pr;
QGraphicsProxyWidget *pr1;


QGraphicsProxyWidget *pr2;
QGraphicsProxyWidget *pr3;
QGraphicsProxyWidget *pr4;
QGraphicsPixmapItem* item1;
QGraphicsPixmapItem* item;

private slots:
void start();
```

This is .cpp class of parent

```
Game::Game(QWidget *parent): QGraphicsView(parent){
scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,466,600);
setScene(scene);

}

void Game::setbackground(){

scene2 = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,400,600);
QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene2);
item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/Ies/uu.jpg"));
scene2->addItem(item);
view->show();
game_function *gm; //call a function in child class
gm->set_buttons();
}
```

child class .h file

```
class game_function:public Game
{
Q_OBJECT

public:

void set_background();
void mainwindow();
void set_buttons();


private slots:
void button_help();
};
```

.cpp file

```
void game_function::set_buttons(){



btn = new QPushButton;
QObject::connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(startgame()));
btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
pr = this->scene2->addWidget(button);
btn->setAutoFillBackground(true);
btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/Ies/main.png"));
btn->setIconSize(QSize(131,41));
pr->setPos(130,430);

btn1 = new QPushButton;
QObject::connect(btn1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(stopgame()));
btn1->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
pro = this->scene2->addWidget(button1);
btn1->setAutoFillBackground(true);
btn1->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/exit.png"));
btn1->setIconSize(QSize(131,41));
pr->setPos(130,500);
```

Comment: `gm` doesn't point to a valid instance of `game_function`. You might want to read more about the difference between classes and objects in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: sir, then how am i going to point this, its working perfecctly when i call from main

Comment: Then `main` probably *does* have a valid instance of `game_function`. Why does the `game_function` class exist at all? Why are those functions not in `Game`?

Comment: sir beacause i put all the functions in a seperate class, in the game class i have intialize the items of the scene. sir, is there ay way i can call this function?

Comment: "game_function *gm;  gm->set_buttons(); " - in these two lines, do you see that gm is uninitialized?  and then you attempt to use it?   undefined behavior.

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps putting the functions in a separate class wasn't as good an idea as it seemed when you started, and that you might benefit from restructuring the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there ay way i can call this function

You might not be too far from trying a polymorphic invocation ...

perhaps if you

A) add "Game::set_buttons()", and make it virtual, perhaps pure virtual, somewhere in class header:

```
class Game:public QGraphicsView,public home{
// ... perhaps after

virtual ~Game(){}

virtual void setbuttons() = 0;

// ...
} // end of class Game
```

then, in method "Game::setbackground()" you can use it ... replace this

```
// undefined behavior - gm not initialized
//game_function *gm; //call a function in child class
//gm->set_buttons();
```

with

```
this->set_buttons();
```

Comment: sir where should i add "Game::set_buttons()"

Comment: @AlexDRex  I updated my answer with more info, suggesting a 'pure virtual' choice.  By "Game::set_buttons()" I simply meant for you to add the additional declaration to somewhere in the Game class.